# Android XML Parsing Error - Parsed SQUARES

Tags: android, xml

I have parsed an 2 different xml files, but when i parse the french version it has squares and weird symbols! What can i do to make it legible?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your program can't handle some of the accented characters used in French (ç, é, â, etc). However, in my experience the phones can handle these characters fine. It's possible that in the process of parsing some of the information was confused/lost. I'd look into either parsing differently (possibly with a different encoding option) or trying to figure out a better way to display these characters on the screen...